# Ajax Login Form - Callback to PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, callback, submit

I'm trying a login in a lightbox via jquery and ajax.
My goal is that after the user logs in successful, he gets redirected to a special site.

The login via jQuery.ajax works fine, but I would like that in case the user is logged in he gets redirected, in case he's not logged in he stays on the login site.
Here's my code so far:

```
$(".logmein").click(function() {  
  var username = $("input#username").val();  
  var password = $("input#password").val();         
  var dataString = 'username='+ username + '&password=' + password + '&login=Login' ; 

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>",  
        data: dataString,  
        success: function() { 
            window.location = "http://test.home/kundenbereich.html"; 
            $('#login_form').html("<div id='message'>Superb</div>");  
        }  
    });  
    return false;  

});
```

The ajax request is performed successfully but, can I generate a callback from php to inform js that the user is not logged in, and then not redirect him via "window.location"? 
In this case he gets redirected anyway, no matter if the login in php was successful or not!

The login function is on the same page(php) and is working with username and password.

It would be great to get some help on this issue.

Sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP:**

```
if (Fe_User::Login($this->getPost('username'), $this->getPost('password'))){  
   echo "true";
}
else{ 
   echo "false";
}
```

**Script :**

```
$.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>",  
      data: dataString,  
      success: function(response) {
          if(response == "true"){ 
           $('#login_form').html("<div id='message'>Superb</div>"); 
           window.location = "http://test.home/kundenbereich.html"; 
          } 
       }  
});
```

Comment: i tried:$.ajax({  
         type: "POST",  
         url: "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>",  
         data: dataString,  
         success: function(response) { 
          if(response.result == 'success'){ 
                 
                 window.location = "http://test.home/kundenbereich.html"; 
             } 
          else{
         $('#login-form').html("<div id='message'>Error</div>");  
     $('#login-form').append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")  
          }
           
          
         }  
       });

Comment: and in the php section: if (Fe_User::Login($this->getPost('username'), $this->getPost('password'))){
   //$this->redirect(CUSTOMERSTART_DE);
   exit(json_encode(array('result'=>'success', 'message'=>'Logged in successfully!')));
   echo true;
   
  }else{
   exit(json_encode(array('result'=>'error', 'message'=>'Logged not successfully!')));
   $error = TRUE;
   echo false;
   
  }

Comment: @user2370234 .. see edit in my answer.. use that code and see if it work's or not

Comment: no, it doesnt goes into the if with a true. Maybe because this is not the only output of this document, i used "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']" and the whole site is outputted on that site, so how could response get only the "true" value?

Comment: I am not good at `php`. But you just need to echo `"true"` or `"false"` if user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

Make your php login function return a json object for instance:

```
// login.php page :
[...] 
if (some_auth_system_log_user_in($username, $password)) {
   exit(json_encode(array('result'=>'success', 'message'=>'Logged in successfully!')));
} else {
   exit(json_encode(array('result'=>'error', 'message'=>'Some error'))); 
}
```

Then the jquery code would be:

```
var username = $("input#username").val();
var password = $("input#password").val(); 
$.post('login.php', {username:username, password:password}, function(response){
  if (response.result == 'success') {
   // redirect
  } else {
   // do something with response.message here
  }
}, 'json');
```

Using json gives you the ability to post back multiple params, or translated messages, etc, so in general is better than just echo `true/false` in your php file

Answer (score 0):

It worked when i putted the output at the start of the php file and let it die(); after outputting the ajax value.
It didnt worked out because i use the same document for the ajax output, therefore the response was the whole Markup of the page.

Thanks for your help